# Injecting springSecurityService into a filter causing error

Tags: spring, grails

Iam using spring-security-core 2.0-RC5 in my grails 2.4.4 application. Recently I implemented the following filter in my application but the problem is when a SignupController request is coming, an error is occurring due to the springSecurityService injection (in the case of signup there is no authentication and no session).

So how can i inject springSecurityService in my filter without catching the signup request.

```html
import com.services.portal.ProfileService;
import com.services.portal.SignupService;
import com.services.portal.UserSessionService;
import com.domain.auth.User;
import com.services.portal.FormProcessService;
import com.services.portal.ProfileService;
import com.services.portal.SignupService;
import com.services.portal.UserSessionService

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.AbstractS2UiController;
import groovy.sql.Sql



class AuthFilters {
 def springSecurityService
 def filters = {
  allExceptIndex(controller: 'login|signup|logout', invert: true) {
   before = {
    if(session["Username"] == null){
     def Username = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getUsername()
     session["Username"] = Username
    }
    if(session["UserId"] == null){
     String userId = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getId()
     session["UserId"] = userId
    }
    if(session["incomingIp"] == null){
     def incomingIp = request.remoteHost
     session["incomingIp"] = incomingIp
    }
    if(session["currUserRole"] == null){
     def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()
     roles = roles.toString().substring(1, roles.toString().length()-1)
     session["currUserRole"] = roles
    }
   }

   after = { Map model ->
   }

   afterView = { Exception e ->
    }
    }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller that handle signup request make it public by using `@Secured(['permitAll'])` before action.

Comment: I already given @Secured(['permitAll']) annotation to the signup controller